# Passing self from a member function to a function in another class

Tags: python, function, self

For context, I am trying to implement a minimax algorithm in python to play tic tac toe. Here's the relevant code:

TicTacToe.py

```
def dumbPlayer(game, gameType):
    return game.successors()[0]


class minimax:
    tree = None
    def minimaxPlayer(self, game, gameType):
        return game.successors()[0]


class TicTacToe:
    def play(self, xPlayer=consolePlayer, oPlayer=consolePlayer, output=consolePrint):
        while self.winner is None:
            output(self)
            if self.turn == 'X': self.move(xPlayer(self, TicTacToe))
            elif self.turn == 'O': self.move(oPlayer(self, TicTacToe))
        output(self, True)
        return
```

main.py:

```
import TicTacToe as TTT

player2 = TTT.minimax.minimaxPlayer
test = TTT.TicTacToe()

test.play(TTT.dumbPlayer, player2)
```

Passing in the dumbPlayer function works fine, the problem comes with the minimaxPlayer function. When the play function calls the minimaxPlayer function, I get the following error:
`TypeError: minimaxPlayer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'gameType'`
From what I understand of python, the "self" parameter is automatically passed to the function and doesn't (or maybe can't) be passed explicitly, so as far as the play function is concerned,
`def dumbPlayer(game, gameType)` and
`def minimaxPlayer(self, game, gameType)`
should be equivalent, but it appears that's not correct in this case.

Is there an easy fix for this? Or will I need to refactor my code? I already have some ideas for how I can restructure the code if I have to, but I'd rather not, and I'd like to know the underlying reason for why this doesn't work how I expect.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `TTT.minimax.minimaxPlayer`, exactly what do you expect this to mean? In particular, **why** is `minimaxPlayer` defined within a class? That's because you *want an instance of `minimax` to exist* - the one that will be referred to as `self` within that code - in order to be able to use the code - right? So. If we just say `TTT.minimax.minimaxPlayer`, *where is the instance*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` argument for an instance method is automatically bound to the instance that you got the method from, but you're accessing the *class*'s version of that method.

Instead of:

```
player2 = TTT.minimax.minimaxPlayer
```

do:

```
minimax_instance = TTT.minimax()
player2 = minimax_instance.minimaxPlayer
```

and it should behave the way you want.

Note: the standard convention in Python is to use CamelCase for class names and snake_case for instance names, which eliminates the need to use weird names like `minimax_instance` to differentiate between the class and the instance.  You probably also want `tree` to be an instance attribute rather than a class attribute (if the idea is to be able to use the Minimax class with different games, you don't want the different instances stepping on each others' state)...

```
class Minimax:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tree = None

    def player(self, game, game_type):
        return game.successors()[0]
```

```
minimax = TTT.Minimax()
player2 = minimax.player
```

Comment: That's a lot simpler solution than I expected, thanks. Not the first time I've had that sort of issue, I should've known.